# Creating many-to-many relation with a junction table

Tags: sql-server

I need to construnct a junction table for many-to-many relations between two parent tables. The design is set. How is it possible to constraint my junction table as a child table when FK's will become duplicates by default?

[image]

```
create table FactInternetSalesReason
( SalesOrderNumber int,
  SalesOrderLineNumber int,
  SalesReasonKey int,
  CONSTRAINT FK_SalesOrder FOREIGN KEY (SalesOrderNumber, SalesOrderLineNumber) REFERENCES FactInternetSales (SalesOrderNumber, SalesOrderLineNumber),
  CONSTRAINT FK_SalesReason FOREIGN KEY (SalesReasonKey) REFERENCES DimSalesReason (SalesReasonKey)
);
```

Comment: What do you mean they'll become duplicates by default? If you put a primary key (or rather, unique clustered index) on (SalesOrderNumber, SalesOrderLineNumber, SalesReasonKey), the same combination of the three should not occur.

Comment: So for each SalesOrderNumber/SalesOrderLineNumber there will be multiple SalesReasonKeys?  I would imagine that each line of an invoice would have a single Sales Reason, making it a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Thanks. The used tables are just for illustrations. In the real case I am using parent tables where there will always be a many-to-many relation between.

Answer (score 1):

A Foreign Key can contain duplicates (try it).   A Primary Key cannot.

Comment: Thanks. It works. My problem was not because of the FK constraint.